# SilverStripe StaticPublishQueue modul's task SiteTreeFullBuildEngine doesn't work

Tags: silverstripe

just came across the https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue module.

the cache creation on "publish and save" works but the bulk generation of all pages with SiteTreeFullBuildEngine doesn't. The only feedback I receive from that task is the following:

```
Adding all pages to the queue. Total: 40

0..
```

Any suggestions how to solve / debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The full build task doesn't immediately perform a build, it just queues all pages to be built. You'll still need to run the BuildStaticCacheFromQueue task (preferably on a cronjob) to do the actual building.

Comment: BuildStaticCacheFromQueue task is setup as daemon like described in the readme.